# assets:precompile end of file reached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I'm attempting to run a `assets:precompile` on my Rails 4 application but I keep getting:

```
rake aborted!
end of file reached
```

I am running this command on my VPS after capistrano complained of the same error. Any ideas?

```
[deploy@skateboxes skateboxes]$ cd /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131024204508 && ( RAILS_ENV=production /usr/local/rvm/bin/skateboxes_rake assets:precompile )
rake aborted!
end of file reached
/var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/marshal.rb:6:in `load'
/var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/marshal.rb:6:in `load_with_autoloading'
/var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/cache/file_store.rb:19:in `block in []'
/var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/cache/file_store.rb:19:in `open'
/var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/cache/file_store.rb:19:in `open'
/var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/cache/file_store.rb:19:in `[]'
/var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:14:in `cache_get'
/var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:84:in `cache_get_hash'
/var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:54:in `cache_asset'
/var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
/var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
/var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
/var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
/var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
/var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
/var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
/var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
/var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
/var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
/var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in define'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This may be happening when there is a file in the cache directory that cannot be unmarshaled. Try cleaning up the temp directory.

https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/v2.10.0/lib/sprockets/cache/file_store.rb

Comment: I tried this an it didn't work.  Do you have any other suggestions?  I also did a git clone for the project.

Comment: @user2974739 Then you may be facing a different issue. Please post another question including your stack trace.